# Visual Studio 2019 - Comment/Uncomment Selection not available for qml code

Tags: visual-studio, qml, command, qt5, comments

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to develop several Qt applications.

Visual Studio provides a very helpful command to comment/uncomment a selection. However, although I can use this command within my C++ and C# projets without problems, I cannot use it with qml code directly. The commands just never appear in the Edit -> Advanced menu, and if I try the Ctrl+K Ctrl+C shortcut I get the following message:

> The key combination (Ctrl+K Ctrl+C) is bound to command (Comment Selection) which is not currently available.

Is there a way to activate a such option for the qml code in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Doesn't work for me too. Thank you for you question at least, now I know that i'm not alone.